# How to set time for Media.VideoPlayer?

Tags: c#, xna, video-player

I have searched the XNA `Media.VideoPlayer` library. It has no direct method for setting a time, but `MediaPlayer` has a `Position` to set playing position.

Is there any indirect way to set the time?

Answer (score 1):

In classic Microsoft style, this simple, yet necessity feature is [not available](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/2459380-allow-setting-a-playback-start-position-within-the):

> Thank you for the suggestion and the spirited commentary. While we understand that this capability is important to you, we are not planning to add this capability to the Windows Phone developer platform. - Cliff Simpkins (Sr Product Manager, Windows Developer)

If you're trying to do this for PC, you might be able to use [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9353583/539997).

If you're going for Xbox or Windows Phone... Sorry!